# How to fix addView/removeView from crashing app

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using a switch method to determine whether or not to show elements in my view based on the selected value of my spinner. I can remove views without any problem but when I change my selection in my spinner then I am unable to add the view back as the app crashes.

I have tried to remove all the views by default and then adding it in each switch case as I need it but the app crashes when I add a new view. I have tried to add and remove the views in each case without using default but still keeps crashing when I add a view to the list.

LinearLayout has an id of reps_layout

```
switch (a){

case "one":                       
myLayout.removeView(rowView.findViewById(R.id.reps_layout));
break;

case "two":
myLayout.addView(rowView.findViewById(R.id.reps_layout));
break;

default:
//myLayout.removeView(rowView.findViewById(R.id.reps_layout));
}
```

When I select case "one" the expected result should have the list but has removed the sets_field. Then when I select case "two" I want to add the reps_layout back to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add your LinearLayout like this. In any case you will need a parent layout.

```js
switch (a){

case "one":                       
myLayout.removeView(rowView.findViewById(R.id.reps_layout));
break;

case "two":
LinearLayout layout =new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
myLayout.addView(layout));
break;

default:
//myLayout.removeView(rowView.findViewById(R.id.reps_layout));
}
```

I dont know your project, but consider that it maybe makes more sense to just set the visibility of the view to GONE rather then hide it.